# Can you restrict the update of a package from a verison in homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

For example, If a package say `A` is currently on a non-latest version say 1.2 (say, latest is 1.5).

Whenever, I do upgrade my brew it upgrades all of the packages, including A. Is there any way to restrict A to not be upgraded and let the other package be upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `brew pin` command.

From `brew pin --help` :

> brew pin formulae:
> Pin the specified formulae, preventing them from being upgraded when
> issuing the brew upgrade command. See also unpin.